# calling array in function

Tags: c, math

I am new to C , and i am working on a program in C to evaluate RHS of green's theorem

Those who don't know about green's theorem here is

[LINK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem)

from wikipedia. 
Now concerning the Right hand side (RHS) of green's theorem , it requires partial differentiation and double integrtation .
I have coded a program in C to calculate partial differentiation of M and L wrt x and y respectively.
Here is the code for it .

Now here comes the problem as you can see that f() is a function which is to be integrated , and  our case it is e[i]-d[j] from the first code . Now the problem is e[i]-d[j] is an array of points so when the function f(u,v) call its value it should return the corresponding values of function at that point. Thus say for example we get f(1,0.8) , then the function e[i]-d[j] should return the value at i=1 and j=0.8 which is not possible subscript of array can't be of float type. So here i am stuck how to call the values from function f.
Any help would be gratly appreciated .

Comment: very long question to me ...

Comment: can we see how `f()` is implimented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you get the values between 0 and 1? Do you just compute the value from i,j on the fly? On your first part of the program only value with int index is computed.

No way to store value using float i,j as array index. If you insist on using the float as index. May be c++ STL map can help you. You can just use i+j as the key to index the values.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the number of points you are playing with by a constant factor - say 10 for your example.  Then you can multiply your array subscript by the same.  In your example, 1, 0.8 becomes (10, 8) and works fine.  This is a variation on fixed point math if you are interested.

Comment: Actually , that would also create a problem . As you can see f(x,c(x)) depend on both x and c(x) and c(x) can be any function .Thus points will vary according to c(x) and not linearly .So, by going your way , we have multiply one point by 10 and just on successive point we may have to mutiply by 100 and the next one maybe by 1000 .